# Pivot Chart in SpreadsheetGear

Tags: charts, pivot, spreadsheetgear

I have Spreadsheetgear and I'm wondering if anyone knows if 2009 edition supports PivotCharts, does anyone know how to do this?

Cheers,
Doga

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look like they NO support Pivot Table

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, seems like the way to do it would be to have a macro create the pivot chart after writing out the excel.